# Cross apply no postgres?

Tags: postgresql, crosswalk

Eu tenho a seguinte situação

```
CROSS APPLY (select top 1 seq.id_prod,
                   seq.id_emp,
                   seq.localizacao,
                   seq.localizacao_modulo,
                   seq.localizacao_nivel,
                   seq.localizacao_rua,
                   seq.localizacao_vao,
                   qtde
            from eq_prod_qtde seq                       
            where seq.id_prod = p.id_prod
              and seq.id_emp = pc.id_emp) ES 
CROSS APPLY (select sum(qtde)
                   qtde
            from eq_prod_qtde seq                       
            where seq.id_prod = p.id_prod) ES1
```

Porem estou tendo dificuldade em fazer esse mesmo processo para postgres.

Comment: Bem vindo ao site, antes de tudo, vale lembrar que aqui [**não é um fórum**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/28595). É importante entender isso para melhorar sua participação no site em perguntas futuras.